# вывод общей суммы калькулятора услуг на js

Tags: javascript

Есть калькулятор услуг
https://jsfiddle.net/6yat7euw/

```
const select = document.querySelectorAll("#select");
const count = document.querySelectorAll(".count");

for (let selects of select){
  selects.addEventListener('change', calc);
}

for (let counts of count){
  counts.addEventListener('change', calc2);
}

function calc() {
    let count = this.parentNode.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.children[0];
    let sum = this.parentNode.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling;
    let result = this.parentNode.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling;

    let price = 0;
    price += parseInt(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
    sum.innerHTML = price;
    price = parseInt(count.value) * price;

    result.innerHTML = price;


    // new

    let priceArr = [...document.querySelectorAll('#result')];
    let priceAll = 0;

};
```

Нужно выводить сумму всех полей + учитывать скидку (внизу страницы). Через цикл с массивом всех значений не получается. Помогите пожалуйста с решением

Answer (score 0):

```
let priceArr = [...document.querySelectorAll('#result')];
let countAll = [...document.querySelectorAll('.count')];
let priceAll = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < priceArr.length; i++){
  priceAll = priceAll + parseInt(priceArr[i].innerHTML);
}

let total = document.querySelector('#main');
total.innerHTML = priceAll;
```